# Can a battery lose electrons?

Tags: charge, batteries

I asked my teacher what would happen if I have a 1Ah battery and I expel (out of the circuit, for example with an electron gun) the electrons with a current of 1A for one hour, in such a way that the battery loses electrons. He told me that the battery would explode due to the electrostatic repulsive force of the ions.

But I'm not sure if he is correct since another professor showed us experimentally how the charge is maintained, he did it by charging the capacitor of parallel plates and then moving them away, in such a way that each plate had a net charge as well as a battery without electrons, am I correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you didn't charge the capacitor plates at 1A for an hour.

Answer (score 1):

In normal operation mode, for the electrons that go out of the battery, an equal amount will return at the other end. So, no.

But then again, yes: if you connect the minus end of the battery with a large metal shield, you have a kind of capacitor, where part of the electrons leave the battery. This is negligible unless the voltage is really high.

Comment: To charge a capacitor we need to typically connect both ends of the capacitor to both ends of the battery. The reaction in the battery cannot proceed (cannot produce current) if both ends are not connected as there will be charge separation and this stops the reaction. There is a negligible charge build up before the reaction stops as you have mentioned. My best estimate is 10^-5 V per V of charge buildup

Answer (score 1):

If you  would do this only for 1/1000 s the batterie would have a charge of 0,001As  wich would leave it at a voltage of about 9 million Volt so it would ionizes the air around it and discharge with lightning.
Did you do any electrostatic? so you could calculate the charge of a say a spere with radius 10cm, thats what I calculated for the batterie.
The amount of charges in electrostatic experiments is very low compared to the charges transported in a current.
so you can never take away so many electrons. you teacher was right in the sense, if you could achieve it you would get a voltage of 3600000 times the 9 million volts I mentioned earlier.
If you take away a smaller amount of electrons the batterie would just be at a smaller voltage against earth, the circuit would be the same. if you connect 1 end of the batterie to 1000V you should not touch it, but it would still do the same thing in a closed circuit as before.